# Passing value from HTML link to use in php if statement on next page

Tags: php, html

I currently have a menu with 4 links, and each link goes to its own php file/page like so:

```
<!--Page One-->
<a href="temp_one.php"><h5 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Template One</h5></a>
<a href="temp_two.php"><h5 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Template Two</h5></a>
<a href="temp_three.php"><h5 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Template Three</h5></a>
<a href="temp_four.php"><h5 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Template Four</h5></a>
```

I'm refactoring this so that I only use one single file that conditionally sets the HTML for the page depending on which link was selected, probably by using GET

I want to change it to get values for each link that direct to a new single page, template.php, and use the value for the page so that the new url would effectively look like this:

```
template.php?1
template.php?2
template.php?3
template.php?4
```

So essentially the same as doing this:

```
<a href="template.php?1"><h5 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Template One</h5></a>
<a href="template.php?2"><h5 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Template Two</h5></a>
<a href="template.php?3"><h5 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Template Three</h5></a>
<a href="template.php?4"><h5 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Template Four</h5></a>
```

The reason is that I want to be able to use the values in an if statement on template.php so that I know which HTML to use like so:

```
<!--Page Two, template.php-->
if(value = 1){
    //HTML for template one
}
elseif(value=2){
    //HTML for template two
}
elseif(value=3){
    //HTML for template three
}
else{
    //HTML for template four
}
```

How can I modify the html of the links to supply the proper value to use in the next page with an if statement?

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Last line of the question: I'm wondering how to modify the HTML to supply that value

Comment: Change your use of = to == (a single = is assignment not a comparison).

Comment: You just edited that in! Anyway, Pupil's answer is mighty fine.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was still going through to make a few edits, I should have gotten it together better before I posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

Pass a variable indicating the template value through URL.

And in php file `template.php`, `$_GET` that variable.

```
<a href="template.php?value=1"><h5 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Template One</h5></a>
<a href="template.php?value=2"><h5 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Template Two</h5></a>
<a href="template.php?value=3"><h5 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Template Three</h5></a>
<a href="template.php?value=4"><h5 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Template Four</h5></a>
```

And in `template.php`,

`$value = isset($_GET['value']) ? $_GET['value'] : 1; // Where 1 is default value.`

```
if($value = 1){
    //HTML for template one
}
elseif($value=2){
    //HTML for template two
}
elseif($value=3){
    //HTML for template three
}
else{
    //HTML for template four
}
```

Comment: So I would set $value, and then I can just do the if statement like I used in my pseudo code?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!